# Can you convert Openpyxl output string to cell number_format'ed string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Is there a dynamic way to convert the string from `cell.value` to match the `cell.number_format`? For example, **in Excel**, the value is **Monday, January 31, 2022**. When read in **Python**, `cell.value` returns **2022-01-31 00:00:00**. Instead of what is returned, I would like to have the string read as it did in **Excel** which was **Monday, January 31, 2022**.  Hoping for this to be dynamic enough to read multiple `cell.number_format`'s.

```
import openpyxl

path = r'Test.xlsx'
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
print(sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 3).value)
print(sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 3).number_format)
```

Comment: Just apply the Python date format you want. There is no library that will automatically convert Excel's number format for you.

Comment: @CharlieClark there really should be at this point. Searched for days in posts that dated back years with no viable solution offered.

Comment: Feel free to write one, that's the beauty of open source.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dateutil` library -

```py
from dateutil.parser import *
parse("2022-01-31 00:00:00")
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0)
parse("Monday, January 31, 2022")                                                                                                  
# datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0)
```

Once you can read in a variety of formats, specifying the output can be done using `strftime` -

```py
parse("2022-01-31 00:00:00")..strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")
# 'Monday, January 31, 2022'
```

Comment: Looking to convert back to the "Monday, January 31,  2022" not away from it. Looking to handle multiple number formats as well, so currency or percent as well.

Comment: Once a string is successfully parsed into a datetime object, having it in a particular format involves specific format - see my edited answer for example. Handling multiple number formats ( I am assuming something like automatically converting `0.01` to `1%`) is a separate question - you should post that separately

Comment: The question was not specific to a format, but all formats as a whole as mentioned in the initial post. A date value was used as a reference point to show the conversion.

Comment: I just saw that. For dates, you might find `dateutil` helpful, for others, you'll probably have to write your own function(s)

Comment: `datetutil` has no understanding of Excel's weird formats for dates and times.